# Сумма должна быть не больше конкретной

Tags: javascript, суммирование

Есть код, который генерирует определенно заданное количество примеров на сложение и проверяет правильность каждого.

```
<head>
<title>Математические задания</title>

<meta charset="utf-8">
<style type="text/css">
body{
        counter-reset: num 0;
    }
    </style>

</head>


<body>
    <div class="primer">

        <span class="num"></span> +
        <span class="num"></span> =
        <input type="number" class="plus" width="5">
        <button type="button">Проверить</button>
        <p class="result"></p>

    </div>
</body>

<script>

    const random = n => Math.round(Math.random() * n);

    let block = document.querySelector('.primer');
    let length = 9;
    let arr = Array.from({length}, _ => block.cloneNode(true));



    document.body.append(...arr);

    document.querySelectorAll('.primer').forEach(div => {

        let sum = 0;

        

        div.querySelectorAll('.num').forEach(span => {

            let num = random(10);

            span.textContent = num;

            sum += num;


        })

        let input = div.querySelector('.plus'),

            button = div.querySelector('button'),

            result = div.querySelector('.result');

        button.addEventListener('click', _ => result.textContent = input.value == sum ? 'Правильно' : 'Неправильно')

    })

</script>
```

Вопрос.
Как сделать, чтобы сумма каждого генерирующегося примера была не больше конкретного числа (например, не больше 10).
В каких только вариациях не пробовал вставлять код с метками или пропусками в случае "sum > 10" - не работает.

Подскажите, как правильно нужно поступить.

Comment: `function randomInteger(min, max) {
  // получить случайное число от (min-0.5) до (max+0.5)
  let rand = min - 0.5 + Math.random() * (max - min + 1);
  return Math.round(rand);
}`

Comment: Вопрос же не в генерации цифр "от" и "до", а чтобы сумма этих чисел была не больше заданного.

Comment: ну смотри на каждой итерации если очередное прибавляемое число даёт сумму больше 10 - выходи из функции

Comment: Вариант вставки 
  
if (sum > 10) {
    return
  }

после "sum += num;"

не помог

Comment: потому что логика не верная. надо в tmp переменную занести sum и сложить с num/ и вот если tmp Ю 10 - то return sum или что там..........либо же.......если работать с sum, то если в итоге sum > 10, то надо **вначале вычесть обратно num** а потом return